# Android Firebase..How i retrieve data

Tags: java, android

I need help in my simple app . I add points features in my app and to firebase also. But how to retrieve points back to same location from firebase??

Comment: Please take a look at Firebase [documentations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/).

Comment: Thanks.. now ill try

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this . I am retrieving all my users of app like this

```
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("users");
     myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userList = new ArrayList<User>();
                dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                //List<User> list= new ArrayList<User>();
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = childDataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    userList.add(user);
                }
                Log.e("hello","childDataSnapshot"+ userList.size());

                adapter.update(userList);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("MY", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks.. now ill try